# Bespokesynth: play a sequence of note (notesequencer) on key press, and generally enable/disable a module on a keypress

Tags: software, daw

In BespokeSynth, how could I play a sequence of notes (`notesequencer`) when pressing a note, and stopping it when pressing it again?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that. As far as I know, they are all based on the `notecounter` node that asks to the `nodesequencer` to play the notes when it's enabled (when it's disabled and re-enabled again, it will restart the sequence from 0).

Note that for this to work, **YOU NEED TO HAVE `notecounter` WITH SYNC DISABLED**, otherwise it will follow the tempo. Note that in Bespoke 1.1.0, I experienced some issues with disabling sync (nothing happens when I click the button), but this can be solved by connecting a `valuesetter` to the sync button and clicking on `set`:

[image]

Therefore, the question is now "**How can we enable/disable a node (here `notecounter`) when a key is pressed?**" and we can do it using various methods:

## Version 1: Simpler: notetopulse and radiosequencer

The simpler solution (thanks Noxy!) is to use the `radiosequencer` (which is basically made exactly for enabling one module at a time):

[image]

Basically, the `notetopulse` sends a "pulse" (a single signal) everytime a note is pressed. This pulse will then go to the next column in the `radiosequencer` (a white cell means "enable", a black means "disabled"): because it contains only two column, it will basically loop between enable/disable, and therefore enable/disable the notecounter that will order `notesequencer` to play.

## Version 2: `notetoggle` (if you prefer to play only when the key is down)

If you prefer to play the sequence only when the key is kept pressed, you can use `notetoggle`, that will simply enable a control when a note is played (thanks Noxy), and disable the control when no note is played:

[image]

If you want instead to play until another note is played (and don't want to use the first solution), then you may like the `notelatch` mode that will keep playing a note until you press the note a second time. To make sure you don't always need to press the same note, you can use `pitchsetter` (or `notecreator` and `notetopulse` if you like complicated setups) that plays a note on a pulse like that:

[image]

## Version 3: Note-stepper/value-setter

This solution is also an equivalent of the first solution (thanks Argon_V/Juraj/WinglessFly/George and jwdungbat), except that the stepper is on the notes instead of on the pulse, and we use then a value setter to configure the value `enable/disable`:

[image]

The `notestepper` will basically forward the note to a different output everytime a new note is pressed. Then, we use `valuesetter` to enable/disable the `notecounter`, which are fired when a pulse reaches them (hence the `notetopulse`).